# is OData IQueryable async?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I'm developing an OData endpoint to return a list of items from a database.

I'm returning an `IQueryable` and letting the front end handling the querying / filtering / expanding / paging through the odata query options.

Consider the following method:

```
[ODataRoute]
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
public IActionResult Get() {
    return Ok(context.Vendors.AsQueryable());
}
```

I understand that `async` is not really needed, because the query is not being materialized here.

In this context, when is the query being materialized?

Is it being done in an asynchronous fashion?

Comment: A method is only async when it's async. The query *is* materialized (in the middleware) when the endpoint is accessed, so async does matter.

Comment: right, in every odata rest api example i've found this is the correct way to call it. However, we set up a small testing camp, and with ~30 concurrent users there has been reports of slowness, and cpu and memory usage went through the roof... I wonder if these API calls are the cause, my theory is that the resources are not being released properly and it keeps piling up...

Comment: Those are different issues. async/await only helps with thread management so that threads do not block on IO calls. Async/Await has no influence on memory/resources/cpu usage. If resources are not being released then you need to check how you registered your types that implement IDisposable and ensure they are not sticking around. DbContext types, as an example, should be registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` (which is the default if you use the extension).

Comment: But you would make more progress if you profiled your application in your test environment as well as your database to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Yep, I'll do that and post back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked a few question Ill try to answer them all and clarify a few questions.

> I understand that async is not really needed

Async is never really needed the question is will async benefit your application.   E.g When a call is being made to the DbContext there is some network operations which take time,  If you do not use async during that time a thread will be waiting for a response, instead of being return to the thread pool to handle other requests.

So yes, it's not needed but it could be useful.

> In this context, when is the query being materialized?

The query is materialized (in the middleware) when the endpoint is accessed,

> Is it being done in an asynchronous fashion?

No, When you pass the Queryable you are just deferring the execution until later this is still being done synchronously, you need to be using the async/await pattern for you to be doing something asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Your query will be materialised during serialisation. When your method is accessed, to return the response in JSON, the serialiser tries to serialise the result. At that point, your query actually hits the database and result returned. 
The application might be slow because of no filters being applied and your query trying to retrieve all the records from the database.

Comment: At the very least, all my front-end calls contains a filter like this one: `?$filter=contains(description, '${term}')`. Unfortunately, an Id and Description is all I have to filter them out. We did create some indexes, and it appears the searches performed better. I just want to clear any unneeded extra overhead from the backend and maybe any misconception I have about the async and IQueryable

Comment: Usually its not a good idea to have indexes on long text fields like description. One thing you could try is to have either a compulsory pagination from client side. Or limit the maximum records to a fixed number say 100. And users need to query again to get next 100. In real world scenario i can not see a scenario where users would look at more than 20 30 records at a time without scrolling or changing a page.

Comment: the scenario is a typeahead, and we also include a $top=10 in it

Comment: Maybe you have too frequent calls to the server. Usually its a good idea to wait for a few milliseconds before sending the query and listen to see if a user is pressing any other key. When user completes typing then send a query once. Not on every key press.